# Why are links to amazon.co.uk are being automatically changed to amazon.com links?

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

For example, see my answer to: [What can I do to baby-proof my home entertainment system?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/what-can-i-do-to-baby-proof-my-home-entertainment-system)

This means the (second and third) links I posted don't actually work if you click on them.

Is this deliberate, should I not be posting links to non-US websites? Or not even posting links to sites like Amazon at all?

Comment: I thought it might simply be a case of the formatting of the links, but after changing to one of the markup styles, the issue remains.  I'll do some research and see if I can find out what is happening here, and why.

Comment: This might be a bug; maybe the site's engine gets some sort of optimization wrong.

Comment: I've asked about this on [SO.meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106294/how-can-we-link-to-products-that-exist-on-amazon-co-uk-but-not-amazon-com-without), as the conversation to [affiliate links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links) is deliberate, but I think the whole .co.uk -> .com may be an unintentional problem.  Hopefully we'll get a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will no longer happen.  We are not an affiliate outside the US (you must have a physical business location within a country to be an affiliate there), so no affiliate links.  If it isn't to the US .com site, it won't be redirected anymore.